# Animation/deformation among developable surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

While making self-study of differential geometry, animation of surfaces showing isometry between Gauss curvature $K<0$ surfaces Catenoid and Helicoid always fascinated me. I often felt that $ K = 0$ animation that morphs between developable surfaces, viz, portions of a disk, a cone and a developable helicoid are easier to formulate for such deformation but I find no such morph animations in text books of differential geometry that I could access.

A cylinder patch cannot isometrically be mapped onto a cone or disk between same $ u,v $ limits even if $ K = 0 $ without stretching so I am leaving out that case, ...as also because converse of Gauss Egregium theorem is not always valid.

These models can be cut out from a paper and demonstrated easily. I can put a demo on YouTube if so desired.

Once done it is possible to visually depict the isometric transformations/mappings and show stages of deformation using Manipulate on Mathematica or other CAS.

EDIT1: Please indicate animation code or Mma Manipulate lines with parametrization.

The following images with Mathematica code  may convey to an extent what I mean, parameters have to be properly made into a single morph.

[image: K=0 DevelopableSurfaces]

Please suggest surfaces parametrization using variables u,v and a morphing parameter p with comments.

```
 Cone = ParametricPlot3D[ 3 u {Cos[t], Sin[t], 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, .3, .7},PlotStyle -> {Yellow}];
Disc = ParametricPlot3D[ 3 u {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, .35, .75}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green}] ;    b = 0.678;
DevHelicoid = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], b t} + u {-Sin[t], Cos[t], b}, {u, 
   0, 2}, {t, 0, 2.5 Pi}];
Show[{Cone, Disc, DevHelicoid}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "TOWARDS_DISC_CONE_DEV. HELICOID_animation ",  Boxed -> False, Axes -> None]
```

As an aside, a cone is *elliptic*, the developable helicoid is *hyperbolic*, a disk is *flat-euclidean* in the area build up sense mentioned in Hilbert, Cohn-Vossen's book " Geometry and Imagination ", which may accordingly be labelled:  Cone = elliptic disk and Developable helicoid = hyperbolic disk. When circumferential dimension $\theta$ is extended, we have the cone growing sidewards axially constrained as a developable helicoid . When extra area is removed we get the cone back. Using a sufficiently large single sheaf or scroll of developable helicoid, we obtain a disks or cones of repeated surface cover.

EDIT2:
A tangential developable been obtained just now, animation is given here with Mathematica code and one frame grab:

[image: Isometry of Cyl_Tangnt_Developable]

```
R = 1; Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[{ Cos[p] (R Cos[th] - u Sin[th]),
    Cos[p] (R Sin[th] + u Cos[th]), Sin[p] (1 + th)}, {th, 0, 
   2 Pi}, {u, 0, 1.6}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {0, 7}}, 
  PlotLabel -> "  ISOMETRY OF TWINING CYL TANGTIAL DEVELOPABLE  ", 
  Mesh -> {25, 5}, PlotStyle -> Yellow], {p, 0, 1.4, .1}]
```

As the cylinder diameter reduces, height increases because lengths are conserved in isometry.Inner edge is always the edge of regression. Cone isometry is much simpler.I shall attempt to depict Cone,Tangential Developable and Disk together in a single animation.

Accordingly here is a way to make  developable part of the Viviani helicoid.When done, it  radially extends out of the spherical center like slant conical generator area portions.

Cut out an annular ring of thin sheet of paper or with plastic sheet, (subtending 360 degrees at center).  Add an extra 77.76 degrees of another such annular ring by attaching
it sideways by an adhesive tape or such, to circumferencially warp the ring.  Next mark  four equi-spaced notches, or, make half width notches at middle (for self-intersection) and join the ring ends making sure you don't make a Moebius strip.

Comment: Sorry, what's the question?

Comment: @Rahulji: The question is: Please suggest surfaces parametrization using variables (u,v) or (u,t) as the case may be along with a morphing parameter p ...and comments.

Comment: load the youtube promise

Comment: @janmarqz I uploaded for the tangential developable case, that I asked. To demonstrate isometric mapping (twisting) take a flat annular ring,cut along radius and fit it around any circular tube. The twisted inner radius is the edge of regression. For Cone, if the symmetrical repetition of cover in a cone development is twice, cone semi angle is sin−1(1/2) etc.The main question is now self-answered. Youtube I would do later.Thanks, your reminder pushed me for this. –  Narasimham

Comment: ...it runs cool!